# map function loop when rendering with ReactJS and concat JSX syntax

Tags: javascript, loops, reactjs

very simple question, when I loop through array when rendering react compnent with `.map` function, say:

```
render() {
        let board = this.props.board;

        return (
            <div>
                 {
                   board.map((piece,index) => {
                       return (
                           <Piece data={piece}/>
                       );
                   })
                 }
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I'm trying to add a break line every 5 pieces so `(index % 5 == 0)` add `<br />` before the `<Piece />`
when I try to concatinate with `+` or to do something like this:

```
board.map((piece,index) => {
      return (
                (index % 5 == 0) ? <br /> : ''
                <Piece data={piece}/>
             );
})
```

I'm getting an output of matrix of `[Object object]`'s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Return an array of `[ <br />, <Piece> ]` if the condition holds and return just the `Piece` component otherwise. [See the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/21960/)

The relevant piece of code is this:

```
return <div>{items.map(function (i, index) {
    if (index % 5 === 0) {
        return [ <br key={index + "break"} />, <Item key={index} num={i} /> ];
    }

    return <Item key={index} num={i} />;
})}</div>;
```

Also, put `key` on the components you return from `map` or other ways that return array-like instances. This way, React doesn't need to take out all the generated components and replace them on each render, but can just find them under the key and update their attributes. Check out [Reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) in React docs to learn more.

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes sense. A question I have in my head now, if I want to wrap every 5 items with a div, how do I do that?

Comment: Please post a new question on Stack Overflow and link to it in a comment, I'll be happy to answer it.

Comment: First of all here's a jsfiddle with a little fix so it work for objects and not only for array of numbers (just added the index to the map loop) https://jsfiddle.net/s048wnoc/.
and here is a link to my second question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856949/jsx-loop-wrapper-for-html-component-on-condition , thank you very much, appriciate it.